# How to properly install SCR3500 card reader on mac - Mac OS X 10.6.8?

Tags: macos, https, ssl-certificate, pki, token

I am trying to login into some secured site and I am required to use SCR3500 card reader. I found and installed some drivers - **http://support.identive-group.com/download_scm/download_scm.php?lang=en**. However this doesn't work. When I try to open https site the ssl_error_handshake_failure_alert pops up. Any ideas how to make it work?

Comment: Did you install the certificates on the card?

Comment: Yes, the card has valid certifiacates. I use it daily.

Comment: I didn't ask if it had valid certificates, I ask, did you import the certs to the os cert store

Comment: How to import certificates from card if I cannot read it? So I need to export this cert on some other machine and import on my mac?

Comment: in windows before Windows 8 you had to use a smart card reader program that would install the certificates for you in Windows 8 that capability is built in all you need is the device drivers.  I would find a program for OS X since it's clear that capability isn't built into the version your using or simply use a supported version of OS x that does have it

Comment: Mac OS X 10.6.8. Just found something in net. Thnx for the hint. Will work on it.

Comment: Doing some more research OS X has a built in driver for the device your using I would use that.  You need to research how to install the certificates on the smart card.  Additionally if the reader has a green light then it read the card

Comment: Found this program. However it doesn't recognize smartcard. The light is red. Then maybe something with drivers is not ok?

Answer (score 0):

Try this [link for the Military CAC SCR-3500 Apple driver (scmccid_5.0.34_mac.zip)](https://militarycac.com/files/scmccid_5.0.34_mac.zip). More details [on this page](https://militarycac.com/usbreaders.htm):

> Note: There is another SCR-3500 reader being sold now with a Part
>   number different from the original 905141.  If you are a Mac user,
>   install this updated driver.  Hold the <kbd>control</kbd> key [on your
>   keyboard] when clicking the .pkg file [with your mouse], select [the
>   word] ***Open***